# Convergence of mixed decreasing-like sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider two non-negative sequence $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that
$$
x_n+y_n\leq\frac{3}{4}x_{n-1}+\frac{1}{4}x_{n-2}+\frac{1}{2}y_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}y_{n-2},
$$
what could we learn about $(z_n):=(x_n+y_n)$? Could it be convergent or divergent? If it could be divergent, under what condition it could be convergent? I could only see it's bounded.

---

Related Q&As

- [$x_{n+m}\le \frac{x_n+x_{n+1}+\cdots+x_{n+m-1}}{m}$. Prove that this sequence has a limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842784/x-nm-le-fracx-nx-n1-cdotsx-nm-1m-prove-that-this-sequence-ha)
- [Convergence of positive sequence in which each term is less than the average of preceding 2 terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533764/convergence-of-positive-sequence-in-which-each-term-is-less-than-the-average-of?noredirect=1#comment7268262_3533764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $(x_n + y_n)$ can of course be convergent: Just choose $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ as constant sequences, or $x_n = 1$, $y_n = 1/2^n$ for a slightly less trivial example.

But it can also be divergent, here is an example: With
$$
\begin{align}
x_n = 0 \, , \, y_n = 3 \quad &\text{if $n$ is even} \\
x_n = 2 \, , \, y_n = 0 \quad &\text{if $n$ is odd} \\
\end{align}
$$
we have
$$
x_n+y_n =\frac{3}{4}x_{n-1}+\frac{1}{4}x_{n-2}+\frac{1}{2}y_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}y_{n-2}
$$
for all $n$, but $x_n + y_n = 3, 2, 3, 2, \ldots$.

Comment: Glad to have your help again! So I guess the coefficients of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ must be proportional in order to make $(z_n)$ convergent...

Comment: @JRen: If they are proportional then $z_n \le c z_{n-1} + (1-c) z_{n-2}$ for some $0 < c < 1$, and then the approach from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3533814/42969 works to show that $(z_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: Yes, I mean if and only if...

Comment: @JRen: “Only if“ is not true: $x_n = 1$, $y_n = 1/2^n$.

Comment: My fault. I mean, "$(z_n)$ has no chance to diverge if and only if coefficients are proportional"