# Prove that $ x_n $ converges if $ x_{n+3}\leq\frac{x_{n+2}+3x_{n+1}+x_n}{5} $.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

> $ \left\{x_n\right\} $ is a sequence and $ x_{n+3}\leq\frac{1}{5}(x_{n+2}+3x_{n+1}+x_n) $ for all $ n\geq 1 $. Prove that $ \left\{x_n\right\} $ is convergent.

I have proved that $ x_n $ is bounded by using induction. Moreover, by simple calculation, $ 5x_{n+2}+4x_{n+1}+x_n $ is decreasing and has limits. I do not know how to go on, can you give me some hints or references?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem ought to help

Comment: @Oli D, can you give me more explicit clarifications?

Comment: Monote convergence theorem says: «$(x_n)$ decreasing/increasing» + «$(x_n)$ bounded below/bouded above » $\implies $ «$(x_n)$ converges». However, I am curious about the statements you make without evidence. Can you show your work about the fact that $(x_n)$ is bounded and decreasing?

Comment: Your claim is false. Consider $x_n=-n$.

Comment: @MatthewH. It becomes correct if you allow “convergence” to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $(x_n)$ either diverges to $-\infty$, or it converges to a finite value.

(The proof works similarly as in [$x_{n+m}\le \frac{x_n+x_{n+1}+\cdots+x_{n+m-1}}{m}$. Prove that this sequence has a limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842784/x-nm-le-fracx-nx-n1-cdotsx-nm-1m-prove-that-this-sequence-ha/1848060#1848060). We don't assume non-negativity here, which is why there are two possible cases.)

First define
$$
 y_n = \max(x_n, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2})
$$
and show that $(y_n)$ is a *decreasing* sequence.

*Case 1:* $(y_n)$ is not bounded below: Then $y_n \to -\infty$, which implies that $x_n \to -\infty$ since $x_n \le y_n$.

*Case 2:* $(y_n)$ is bounded below, and therefore convergent. Let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$. We show that $(x_n)$ converges to the same value $L$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then
$$
 x_n \le y_n < L + \epsilon
$$
for all sufficiently large $n \ge N$. It follows that for $n \ge N+2$
$$
 x_{n+1} \le \frac 15 (x_{n-2} + 3 x_{n-1} + \color{red}{x_{n}}) < \frac 15 (4(L + \epsilon) + x_n) \\
 x_{n+2} \le \frac 15 (x_{n-1} + 2 x_{n} +\color{red}{x_{n}}+ x_{n+1}) < \frac 15 (4(L + \epsilon) + x_n) \\
 x_{n+3} \le \frac 15 (\color{red}{x_{n}} + 3 x_{n+1} + x_{n+2}) < \frac 15 (4(L + \epsilon) + x_n) \\
$$
and therefore
$$
 y_{n+1} < \frac 15 (4(L + \epsilon) + x_n) \, .
$$
But $(y_n)$ *decreases* to $L$, so that
$$
 L < \frac 15 (4(L + \epsilon) + x_n) 
\implies L - 4 \epsilon < x_n
$$
for $n \ge N+2$.

We have shown that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that for $n \ge N+2$
$$
  L - 4 \epsilon < x_n \le L + \epsilon
$$
and that proves $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$.